# change function on md-select doesn't work? angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-select

This is the html:

```
<md-select placeholder="Veileder {{i+1}}" (change)="updateSupervisorList(i)">
            <md-option *ngFor="let supervisor of displayedsupervisorList" >{{supervisor}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
```

This is the method in the .ts file (displayedsupervisorList is a string[] with names)

```
updateSupervisorList(i: number){
  console.log("updatesupervisorlist");
  this.displayedsupervisorList.splice(i,1);
}
```

When i choose an option nothing happens, it doesn't even go to the console.log

Comment: What version of `material2` are you using? (post package.json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<md-select placeholder="Veileder {{i+1}}" 
  ngModel (ngModelChange)="updateSupervisorList(i)" name="veileder">
```

Answer (score -1):

Event *change* does not work, but you can use *select* method on *md-option*.

[Here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/select) you can find documentation of *md-select* from *angular-material*.
In a *API REFERENCE tab* describes all methods and parameters of md-select and md-option components

I hope that I helped you

Comment: There's a `change` event - [Proof](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/select/select-demo.html#L38)